# engati : Get button click value

Tags: chatbot

**Engati Chatbot question.**
**Engati tag is not exist yet so i manually add here.**

I wanna try to get dynamic bank account number using custom code which shown as below

```
process({   
 "data": {    
   "type": "msg_options",     
   "text": "Choose an Account Number",     
   "options": [       
      {         
        "text": "12345678901234",         
        "postback": "flow_788224AF8006422BA5E587720DE3B252"       
      }, {         
        "text": "43210987654321",         
        "postback": "flow_788224AF8006422BA5E587720DE3B252"       
      }     
    ]   
  } 
});
```

Here in example i set two options and set same flow [flow_788224AF8006422BA5E587720DE3B252]

Now i want to get which option selected by user in flow_788224AF8006422BA5E587720DE3B252

Should i write any dynamic script for that or use any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by below code

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "msg_options",
    "text": "Choose an option",
    "options": [       
       {         
          "text": "12345678901234",         
          "postback": "flow_788224AF8006422BA5E587720DE3B252||data_account=12345678901234"       
       }, {         
          "text": "43210987654321",         
          "postback": "flow_788224AF8006422BA5E587720DE3B252||data_account=43210987654321"       
       }     
    ] 
  }
}
```

Also you can user multiple variable like

**"postback": "flow_788224AF8006422BA5E587720DE3B252||data_account=43210987654321&data_bank=ICICI"**

**data_** is set to define attributes
and use in send message with {{account}}